# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Python and Sqllite3

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

My Code:

From Python 3.8

def email_address_grab(email_list):

```
""" This function takes in a list of emails and puts them into a sql database"""


#import module
import sqlite3 as sql


#Setup sql
#create connection for sql
connection = sql.connect("emailList.db")

#create cursor
crsr = connection.cursor()

 #create sql table
cmd = """CREATE TABLE emails (
email_handle TEXT,
email_domain VARCHAR(20));"""
crsr.execute(cmd)


#iterate through email list
index = 0
for email in email_list:
    #split email with a delimiter of "@"
    email_list[index] = email.split('@')
    index += 1

#while loop to put all data into table
ct = 0
while ct <= (len(email_list) - 1):
    for i in range(0, len(email_list)):
        for j in range(0, len(email_list)):
            email_address_1 = email_list[i]
            email_address_2 = email_list[j]
            cmd = f"""INSERT INTO emails (email_handle, email_domain) VALUES ({email_address_1}, {email_address_2});"""
            crsr.execute(cmd)
    ct += 1


#get the contents of the table
crsr.execute("SELECT * FROM emails;")

#store contents in a variable
email_address_list = crsr.fetchall()

#save changes to sql table
connection.commit()

#close connection
connection.close()


#return print statement for data
return print(email_address_list)
```

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:/Users/USER/Desktop/email grabber.py", line 79, in 
email_address_grab(["testemail123@gmail.com"])

File "c:/Users/USER/Desktop/email grabber.py", line 58, in email_address_grab
crsr.execute(cmd)

sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: 'testemail123', 'gmail.com'

Comment: you need quotes around the values you're trying to submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because this is your final command string:

```py
"""INSERT INTO emails (email_handle, email_domain) VALUES (testemail123, gmail.com);"""
```

while what is a *valid* string is:

```py
"""INSERT INTO emails (email_handle, email_domain) VALUES ("testemail123", "gmail.com");"""
```

So you should be using something like:

```py
cmd = f"""INSERT INTO emails (email_handle, email_domain) VALUES ('{email_address_1}', '{email_address_2}');"""
```

Although, with `sqlite3`, you should be passing in parameters with the `execute` call. This is to help prevent **sql injection attacks** because the way that you are using formatted strings can result in catastrophic attacks.

You should pass parameters to `sqlite3` instances like this:

```py
cmd = """INSERT INTO emails (email_handle, email_domain) VALUES (?, ?);"""
crsr.execute(cmd, (email_address_1, email_address_2))
```

Comment: When I input:                                                                                                               
cmd = f"""INSERT INTO emails (email_handle, email_domain) VALUES ('{email_address_1}', '{email_address_2}');"""
       crsr.execute(cmd                  ) I get    File "c:/Users/USER/Desktop/email grabber.py", line 58, in email_address_grab
    crsr.execute(cmd)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "richazon543": syntax error

Comment: Ah, I think it might have to be double quotes. But you should really be using that last snippet of code

Comment: Yeah it was double quotes